# Getting null after unmarshalling using JaXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aws:TrafficHistoryResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
    <aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11">
        <aws:OperationRequest>
            <aws:RequestId>6b09364e-ac0d-686c-cb95-0b1393fd234e</aws:RequestId>
        </aws:OperationRequest>

        <aws:ResponseStatus xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
            <aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode>
        </aws:ResponseStatus>
    </aws:Response>
</aws:TrafficHistoryResponse>
```

### POJO classes:

### package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.mycom.web;
```

### AlexaResult

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TrafficHistoryResponse")
public class AlexaResult implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3068403572663448394L;


    private AlexaResponse alexaResponse;

    @XmlElement(name="Response", namespace="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11")
    public AlexaResponse getAlexaResponse() {
        return alexaResponse;
    }

    public void setAlexaResponse(AlexaResponse alexaResponse) {
        this.alexaResponse = alexaResponse;
    }




}




JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AlexaResult.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(webTrafficDetails);
        AlexaResult result = (AlexaResult) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

But I am getting `result.getAlexaResponse().getAlexaHistoryResult()` as null ? Anything am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assumption

All your model classes are in the same package

---

### Original Answer

You should change the namespace on the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to be the most used namespace which is `http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11`.

**package-info.java**

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11", 
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.mycom.web;
```

**AlexaResult**

Since the `TrafficHistoryResponse` element is the only one with a different namespace, use the `namespace` property on the `@XmlRootElement` annotation to override it to be `http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TrafficHistoryResponse", namespace="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/")
public class AlexaResult implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3068403572663448394L;


    private AlexaResponse alexaResponse;

    @XmlElement(name="Response")
    public AlexaResponse getAlexaResponse() {
        return alexaResponse;
    }

    public void setAlexaResponse(AlexaResponse alexaResponse) {
        this.alexaResponse = alexaResponse;
    }

}
```

---

### UPDATE #1

> Thanks for your answer. I tried this but alexaResponse is coming as
>   null. any suggestion?

When I make the two changes stated above and run the code below:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AlexaResult.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        AlexaResult result = (AlexaResult) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
        System.out.println(result.getAlexaResponse().getAlexaHistoryResult());
    }

}
```

I get the following output:

```
com.mycom.web.AlexaHistoryResult@5872922a
```

---

### UPDATE #2

FYI, I just noticed that you should have `@XmlElementWrapper(name="HistoricalData")` on the `data` property in the `HistoricalData` class.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;

public class HistoricalData implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1284437498477880205L;

    private List<Data> data;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="HistoricalData")
    @XmlElement(name = "Data")
    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

**Output**

With this second update, below is what I get when I marshal the instance of `AlexaResult` back to XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:TrafficHistoryResponse xmlns="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11" xmlns:ns2="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
    <Response>
        <TrafficHistoryResult>
            <Alexa>
                <TrafficHistory>
                    <HistoricalData>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-17</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>127970</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>507000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-18</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>125880</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>503000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-19</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>120840</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>497000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-20</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>86640</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>461000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-21</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>85550</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>463000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-22</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>130800</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>507000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-23</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>128410</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>501000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-24</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>127350</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>502000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-25</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>125800</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>499000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-26</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>123290</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>493000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-27</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>87840</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>459000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-28</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>86350</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>462000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-29</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>130110</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>500000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-09-30</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>130220</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>498000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-01</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>131730</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>500000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-02</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>127800</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>496000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-03</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>100820</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>461500</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-04</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>73500</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>421300</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-05</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>72850</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>427600</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-06</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>100790</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>467800</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-07</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>103560</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>469200</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-08</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>103220</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>471900</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-09</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>104180</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>470700</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-10</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>97980</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>461700</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-11</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>76100</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>437200</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-12</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>74820</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>435900</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-13</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>102590</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>469300</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-14</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>103400</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>467400</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-15</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>103040</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>475000</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-16</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>102640</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>465400</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                        <Data>
                            <Date>2014-10-17</Date>
                            <PageViews>
<PerMillion>99020</PerMillion>
                            </PageViews>
                            <Rank>1</Rank>
                            <Reach>
<PerMillion>459800</PerMillion>
                            </Reach>
                        </Data>
                    </HistoricalData>
                </TrafficHistory>
            </Alexa>
        </TrafficHistoryResult>
    </Response>
</ns2:TrafficHistoryResponse>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but alexaResponse is coming as null. any suggestion?

Comment: @user755806 - The changes I stated work for me.  I have updated my answer to include the demo code I used.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you change the `aws` namespace from:

```
xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"
```

to

```
xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"
```

First of all, make sure this is corect.

Next, if this is the case then you have elements in different namespaces in your document. In this case you have basically two options:

- Use `package-info.java` to define the most used namespace (I think this will be `http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11` in this case). Omit `namespace` in `@XmlElements` (and further annotations) which use this namespace.
- Do not use `package-info.java` and write `namespace` in all of the `@XmlElements`.

`package-info.java` can provide a "default" namespace which will be used to "qualify" elements (defined by `@XmlElement`, `@XmlElements`, `@XmlElementWrapper`, `@XmlElementRef`, `@XmlElementRefs`) if they don't provide a `namespace`. But you can also provide the `namespace` explicitly:

```
@XmlElement(name="TrafficHistoryResult",
            namespace="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11")
```

Comment: I cannot change the namespace since the xml is webservice response. I tried @XmlElement(name="TrafficHistoryResult",
            namespace="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05").But still I amgetting null result.

Comment: I understand. Check my answer once again. You have tried the wrong URI, try `http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11`. And be careful with `/` at the end. One of the namespaces has it, the other one has not.

Comment: If i change the name space to /2005-07-11 as you said, I am getting below the exception. javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/", local:"TrafficHistoryResponse"). Expected elements are <{http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11}TrafficHistoryResponse>

Comment: @user755806 You changed it on the wrong `@XmlElement` then.

Comment: Can you please give me sample code where to make the changes?